understand evaluation time in prometheus web UI

Hi.Can anyone explain to me why does evaluation time graph show almost two and half hour ago and not the present time?

The timestamp for your graph is 4/2 13:03 (field right after timeframe) and then you have it going back one hour, thats why the graph is starting at 12:03.

As you see, my system time is 16:04 and i don't have data from 12:37.also that one hour that you mention is for X dimension and is irrelevant to my question.I would have appreciate if you have any comment for me to understand this.@Isaiah4110

I think you should first check out your timezone. Because Prometheus always keep data in UTC timezone. However, You can select the checkbox "Use local time" in the Prometheus control panel.
